# Get ember component (SVG) parent element width and height

Tags: ember.js, svg

I am trying to create an SVG wrapper using components. My app will allow users to render different SVGs from a list.

I would like those SVG to fit the screen; so I thought that I would get the DOM parent element width and height, before the component get inserted on the screen.

To do so here is the code I tried. It seems that the issue is related to the SVG because when the `tagName` is set to `span` or even not set; things works as expected.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'svg',
  attributeBindings: ['height', 'width', 'viewBox', 'xmlns', 'version'],
  width: getParentWidth(),

  getParentWidth: function() {
    return this.$().parent().width();
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to get the the width on the didInsertElement hook?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to wait until the element gets inserted into the DOM.

```
  getParentWidth: function() {
    return this.$().parent().width();
  }.observes('didInsertElement')
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't set `width: getParentWidth()`

Comment: +1 - it set me on the right direction. I have a draw function to render the svg.   In ember 2.4 im using this `getParentWidth: Ember.computed('didInsertElement', function() {
        return this.$().parent().width();
    }),` to get the width of the components parent element. I include this explanation because though it may not have answered the asked question it helped answer mine